# SWRevealController button not firing the revealToggle: action

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealController` in my application and have followed the instructions described here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

However it appears that the `sidebarButton` does not fire the toggle

I have set it up as follows:

Initial View Controller class has been set to `SWRevealViewController`

Segue has been created linking it to the `NavigationViewController` and the segue has been given the identifier sw_front

I have a `menuViewController` that is subclassed from `UITableViewController`

I created a segue from the Initial view Controller whose class is `SWRevealViewController` to the `menuViewController` and gave that segue an identifier sw_rear

In `mainViewController.m` I have imported `SWRevealViewController.h` and I have set the menu button

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
```

In mainViewController in the viewDidLoad method I have the following:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [self revealViewController];

if ( revealViewController )
{
    [self.sidebarButton setTarget:self.revealViewController];
    [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector(revealToggle:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

When I run the application and put a breakpoint at the point where I am setting the target and Action for button I can see that they are being assigned.

However when I click the button the `revealViewController.revealToggle` method is not firing.

I was wondering if maybe I need to set up the event that fires it - as in for a `touchupInside` event. But I've looked through all the sample code https://github.com/appcoda/Slideout-Sidebar-Demo/tree/master/SidebarDemo and can't see where they have done that.  I'm at a loss to figure out why the revealToggle action is not firing.

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the button on the action on `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;`

[image]

You can see an example of this one
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerStoryboardExample2

Comment: Thanks Runia but I have already connected the bar Button item to the storyboard as you've outlined above.  I did think perhaps it is because it is positioned on the navigation bar provided by the Navigation Controller that that might be part of the problem, but when I click the button I can see it respond to my touch (it highlights) but it does not fire the revealToggle Method.

Comment: @LindaKeating look at my simple example https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4RHbK4d8zRRFdDNExSMThjTVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks so much I had a good luck at your project and eventually realised I had used the wrong UIControl - I had a UIButton instead of a BarButtonItem.

Comment: @LindaKeating good luck to you! And do not forget to mark the correct answer;)